# How do change and then immediately save a Rails model instance from a validation callback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, mongoid

I'm using mongoid, and I want to migrate my documents one at a time. To do this, I've tried doing the migration in an `after_initialize` callback, but I can't seem to `save()` from there without triggering the same validation and infinite recursion. Is there a better callback to use, or a different thing I should be looking at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried passing :validate => false into the save? That allows you to bypass validations.

As per the original question,

```
instance.update_attributes(new_attr_hash)
```

will immediately save after updating the instance, but you can't bypass validations with update_attributes.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `before_save`, and then go through the whole collection and save them again outside the callback, instead of just initializing them like I assume you were doing before.